# Nginx: Reroute Subdomains to Django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config

How to catch and reroute subdomains **internally** in Nginx to Django's URL dispatcher?

```
api.project.org/ -> /api/
www.project.org/ -> /www/
project.org/ -> /www/
```

I want to get something like this:

```
location api.project.org/ {
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080/api/;
}
```

And the end user still should see those subdomains, not like if the server will return `301` and location like `project.org/www/`.

Comment: you can use rewrite

Comment: @vorujack but how can I do it with `rewrite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each subdomain you must write a nginx server configuration

```
server {
    server_name api.project.org;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/$1 break;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /api$1 break;
        uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8080;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

the second rewrite prepend /api/ to each urls and pass it to uwsgi script.

the first rewrite is for django redirects to work. because django doesnt know about your system configuration when you return HttpResponseRedirect your URL is like this:

```
http://api.project.org/api/subdomain
```

so we must prevent adding api to begining of url when this type of request reached.